# Pack pandas groupby output to a container

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a large `dataframe` on which I am running a `groupby` operation like this.

```
df_3[filter_3].groupby(grpby_3).agg({'AOT in Cases':lambda x: round(100*np.mean(x),0),'COT by ME (1.3.2)':lambda x: round(100*np.mean(x),0)}).unstack('Quarter')
```

That gives me a multi-index output like this:

```
                                            AOT in Cases            COT by ME (1.3.2)   
                                 Quarter    2022Q2  2022Q3  2022Q4  2022Q2  2022Q3  2022Q4
                              Lane  Carrier Scac                        

BLOOMINGTON, CA - APPLE VALLEY, CA  LEGS    94.0    86.0    95.0    100.0   95.0    98.0
```

What I want is to pack it in a container (ideally a tuple) for 'AOT in Cases' & 'COT by ME (1.3.2)' and eliminate the quarter column. Something like this.

```
                          Lane  Carrier Scac   AOT in Cases             COT by ME (1.3.2)                           

BLOOMINGTON, CA - APPLE VALLEY, CA  LEGS       (94.0,   86.0,   95.0)   (100.0, 95.0,   98.0)
```

Ideally if it can be coded on the same goupby line that's the best. If not I can run another line to get the desired result.

I am thinking may be `apply(lambda x: ))` somehow may help. But could not get head around it.

Any lead would be helpful.

---

An additional bonus question, not that important though. You would notice that in the `groupby().agg()` method I am doing a lambda operation for a multiplication on the 'mean', is there a faster & shorter way to do that?

```
agg({'AOT in Cases':lambda x: round(100*np.mean(x),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While nobody answered, I found a similar approach in one of the other questions asked differently. Which suggests to use `list(zip(series1,series2,...))` & it solved my problem.

I could have deleted the question, but considering somebody else might have come with this question again, just left it like that.